# How to list all Kafka zookeeper bootstrap servers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I would like to be able to programmatically (or use a a shell script) to list all the zookeeper bootstrap servers for each of my environments.

If i just know one of the bootstrap servers can I get a list of all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All active brokers are registered under `/brokers/ids/[brokerId]`,  you can query ZNode information via any ZK client(for example org.I0Itec.zkclient). All you need is zkQuorum address.

```
zkClient = new ZkClient(properties.getProperty("zkQuorum"), zkSessionTimeout, zkConnectionTimeout,
                ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$);
```

[Kafka data structures in Zookeeper](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+data+structures+in+Zookeeper)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps directly, but I used the following to find a bootstrap server from a Kafka zookeeper:

```
zkCli.sh -server host:port
[zkCli prompt] ls /kafka
[..., brokers, ...]
[zkCli prompt] ls /kafka/brokers
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[zkCli prompt] ls /kafka/brokers/1
[1]
[zkCli prompt] get /kafka/brokers/1
>> broker info<<
```